# Is IceHrmPro opensource

Tags: open-source, web-apps

IceHrm Human resource management is opensource and freely available here Is IceHrm Pro opensource and can I modify its code after purchase and distribute?

Comment: *It is open source* and *Is it opensource* in one 'question'?

Comment: It’s off-topic to ask about a specific software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IceHrmPro](https://icehrm.com) is a commercial software released with full source code. It adds modules like leave management, training management, expense management and some advanced employee management features on top. Just like the open source application, IceHrm pro is also self hosted. After purchase client receive a download link and the software should be hosted on there own servers. Client can only use it for the company it is licensed to. The source code can be modified to be used by the company it is licensed to but it doesn't allow the client to distribute modified or unmodified application.

Comment: Because you have been employed by IceHrm.com, you should admit to it when recommending the purchase of its commercial software.

Comment: Yes we do that. But I've been asked this question as a pre-sale question for many times. So having more sources to communicate it isn't a bad thing at all :)